# A C# Linq to Sql query that uses SUM, Case When, Group by, outer join, aggregate and defaults

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I've been searching for possible solutions and attempting this for several hours without luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I've got a Sql statement which I'm trying to put together as a C# LINQ query.

Here is the working SQL:

```
SELECT up.UserProfileID
    ,up.FirstName
    ,up.LastName
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN ul.CompletionDate IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE ISNULL(ul.Score, 0)
    END) AS TotalScore
FROM dbo.UserProfile up
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserLearning ul ON up.UserProfileID = ul.UserProfileID
WHERE up.ManagerUserProfileID IS NULL
GROUP BY up.UserProfileID, up.FirstName, up.LastName
```

I've tried several different ways but seem to end up with either a statement that doesn't return what I want or doesn't execute successfully

My current (non-working) code looks something like this:

```
var pd = from up in db.UserProfiles
     join ul in db.UserLearnings on up.UserProfileID equals ul.UserProfileID into temp
     from upJOINul in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new UserLearning() { Score = 0 })

     where up.ManagerUserProfileID.Equals(null)

     group up by new
     {
         UserProfileID = up.UserProfileID,
         FirstName = up.FirstName,
         LastName = up.LastName,
         TotalScore = up.UserLearnings.Sum(u => u.Score)
     };
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several more attempts and further use of google I finally managed to get a working solution. I hope it'll be of use to someone else.

```
var pd = db.UserProfiles.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(up => up.ManagerUserProfileID.Equals(null))
    .Select(up => new
    {
        UserProfileID = up.UserProfileID,
        FirstName = up.FirstName,
        LastName = up.LastName,
        TotalScore = up.UserLearnings
            .Where(ul => ul.CompletionDate.HasValue && ul.Score.HasValue)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Sum(ul => ul != null && ul.Score.HasValue ? ul.Score : 0)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked for, but if you have a working complex SQL query, that is fairly static, put it in a stored proc, and drag that SP to your LINQ DataContext.

The LINQ provider has to compile your query to sql every time it's called, and that takes time, and server CPU cycles. If it's a complex query, it can eat up significant resources. Also may miss some optimizations you can do with straight SQL.

Unless of course there is a purpose to it.

If you have ORM problem, grap the actual SQL commands, take a look at it, and compare with what you want to achieve. Can you show the generated SQL as well, so we can find the difference easier?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I normally favor putting complex queries in Sql for reasons that you mention. However, performance is very low on priority on this project and it is preferred to keep such logic in code. I put together the sql code in a few minutes but I'm still learning LINQ which is another reason I want to be able to solve this... simply to learn myself

Comment: With regards to showing generated Sql, the C# code I put up currently gives me this runtime error: "The entity or complex type 'CPDModel.UserLearning' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: I guess the `DefaultIfEmpty(new UserLearning() { Score = 0 })` part is the cause of that error. But it should work even if you leave just a `DefaultIfEmpty()`, because it should translate to a left join and sum, and sql should take care about it.

Comment: If I only use DefaultIfEmpty() as suggested, the code does run, but I get a TotalScore result of null on 1 of the results. It also does not take into consideration the CompletionDate and the Sums are not correct.

Comment: Akos, its a bit too much guessing and 'shoulding' =) Anybody else have any suggestions?